# Cannot connect to Database Sybase IQ using ODBC

Tags: python, database-connection

I'm trying to connect to a Sybase IQ using and ODBC connection. I'm able to connect to it in R, but in Python I can't.

I have tried several iterations of the below, but it is not connecting.

```py
from sqlalchemy import 
create_engineengine=create_engine('sybase+pyodbc:///DSN =DI')
```

Below is a sample of R code that works perfectly,

```r
library(odbc)
con <- dbConnect(odbc(), dsn = "DI")
```

any suggestions?

Comment: What error message are you getting? It's hard to debug this, without knowing, what is going wrong.

Comment: Below is the error that i am getting:
engine=create_engine('sybase+pyodbc:///DSN =DI')
 SAWarning: No driver name specified; this is expected by PyODBC when using DSN-less connections
  "No driver name specified; "

Comment: What is the driver you are using? @Jordan9588